# Difference between pull out /draw out /bring out in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence :
' The kids bring all the chairs and tables out, and they set them up.'
I would like to know if we may use instead 'pull out' or 'draw out', if in this case they are synonyms.

I just assume that 'take out' would mean outside instead of in the classroom, but it's hard to figure the nuances between the others phrasal verbs.

Comment: "Pull out" or "draw out" sounds more like specifically withdrawing the chairs and tables from wherever they were before.  It's hard to say without seeing more context, but neither one sounds as natural or general to me as "bring out".  Is there more context?   Can you post the entire paragraph, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal choice of verb is best illustrated with some examples.

If the chairs and tables were kept in a storeroom and had to be set up in a hall, somebody standing in the hall might say:

> The kids bring all the chairs and tables out, and they set them up.

However, an observer inside the storeroom would say:

> The kids take all the chairs and tables out, and they set them up.

So, objects are generally brought towards the speaker and taken away from him/her. Additionally, the speaker, located elsewhere, might ask someone to fetch/bring/take the chairs from the storeroom and set them up in the hall. It's just a question of which verb feels most natural in context.

*Take out* doesn't necessarily imply outside of a building, just out of a particular area/space/room.

*Pull out* and *draw out* both imply that the objects have been stored in such a fashion that they first need to be withdrawn by being pulled out before they can be carried away.

Answer (score 0):

Might this be a regional difference in speaking? In the USA we do not use  "draw out" in this way; "take out" is the colloquial, "bring out" is what an American English teacher might say. From my reading of British English "The kids pull the chairs out" sounds very natural.

I agree with Ronald that bring and take imply position but seems fussy in this case.